# How to make infinite enumerator

Tags: ruby, enumerator

Suppose I have an array

```
array = [1,2,3]
```

I need to create such a enumerator that will return values in cyclic manner:

```
array.next #=> 1
array.next #=> 2
array.next #=> 3
array.next #=> 1
array.next #=> 2
...
```

I believe there's a neat solution for that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Array#cycle`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-cycle) / [`Enumerable#cycle`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle) does what you are looking for:

```
e = [1,2,3].cycle  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:cycle>

e.next             #=> 1
e.next             #=> 2
e.next             #=> 3
e.next             #=> 1
e.next             #=> 2
```

`(1..3).cycle` returns equivalent values.